# Access vba function getting stopping when other form opens as part of function

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

I have the following function running on form load when the database opens.  I know something is missing but I am not sure what exactly.  The code runs fine until it opens a form so the user can select a printer.  Then the form has it's own that it works through.
I put a break in and the code stops on the SelectPrinter sub so I guess I need that code to return to the function or can I write the code into the function?

This is the function:

```
Option Compare Database
Function PrintReports()

Dim ExeCount As Long
Dim ExdCount As Long
Dim ExiCount As Long
Dim ExnCount As Long
Dim ExpCount As Long
Dim Answer As Integer
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
'Create Ex e Table
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT tbl_AHAD.*, IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is           Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,[Last_Insp_Date])) 
AS Due_Date " & _  
"INTO tbl_Ex_e " & _
"FROM tbl_AHAD " & _
"WHERE (((IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,      
[Last_Insp_Date])))<=Date()) " & _
"AND ((tbl_AHAD.Device_Class) In ('Ex e','Ex eb','Ex ed','Ex em','Ex    
emb','Ex mb','Ex mbe','Ex me')))" & _
"ORDER BY tbl_AHAD.Maint_Item"
'Create Ex d Table
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT tbl_AHAD.*, IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is    
Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,[Last_Insp_Date])) AS Due_Date " & _
"INTO tbl_Ex_d " & _
"FROM tbl_AHAD " & _
"WHERE (((IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,  
[Last_Insp_Date])))<=Date()) " & _
"AND ((tbl_AHAD.Device_Class) In ('Class 1','Ex d','Ex de','Ex dmb')))" & _
"ORDER BY tbl_AHAD.Maint_Item"
'Create Ex i Table
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT tbl_AHAD.*, IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is  
Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,[Last_Insp_Date])) AS Due_Date " & _
"INTO tbl_Ex_i " & _
"FROM tbl_AHAD " & _
"WHERE (((IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4, 
[Last_Insp_Date])))<=Date()) " & _
"AND ((tbl_AHAD.Device_Class) In ('Ex i','Ex ia')))" & _
"ORDER BY tbl_AHAD.Maint_Item"
'Create Ex n Table
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT tbl_AHAD.*, IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is 
Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,[Last_Insp_Date])) AS Due_Date " & _
"INTO tbl_Ex_n " & _
"FROM tbl_AHAD " & _
"WHERE (((IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,
[Last_Insp_Date])))<=Date()) " & _
"AND ((tbl_AHAD.Device_Class) In ('Ex n','Ex nA','Ex nR')))" & _
"ORDER BY tbl_AHAD.Maint_Item"
'Create Ex p Table
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT tbl_AHAD.*, IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is   
Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,[Last_Insp_Date])) AS Due_Date " & _
"INTO tbl_Ex_p " & _
"FROM tbl_AHAD " & _
"WHERE (((IIf([Last_Insp_Date] Is Null,Date(),DateAdd('yyyy',4,   
[Last_Insp_Date])))<=Date()) " & _
"AND ((tbl_AHAD.Device_Class) In ('Ex p'))) " & _
"ORDER BY tbl_AHAD.Maint_Item"

DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
'Open message box to ensure user wants to continue

ExeCount = DCount("ID", "tbl_Ex_e")
ExdCount = DCount("ID", "tbl_Ex_d")
ExiCount = DCount("ID", "tbl_Ex_i")
ExnCount = DCount("ID", "tbl_Ex_n")
ExpCount = DCount("ID", "tbl_Ex_p")

Answer = MsgBox("There are " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ExeCount & "   Ex e Reports   
" & vbCrLf & ExdCount & "   Ex d Reports " & vbCrLf & _
ExiCount & "   Ex i Reports" & vbCrLf & ExnCount & "   Ex n Reports" &  
vbCrLf & ExpCount & "   Ex p Reports" & _
vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Records to Print", vbOKCancel)
'If Ok then print all reports
If Answer = vbOK Then
DoCmd.OpenForm "SelectPrinter", , , , , acDialog
**'Stopping here**
 Set Application.Printer = _
      Application.Printers(cboDestination.ListIndex)
DoCmd.Close acForm, "SelectPrinter", acSaveYes

   If ExpCount > 0 Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Ex_p"

End If
' Switch back to original default printer
Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(strDefaultPrinter)
Else
Exit Function
End If
'Update table with today's date

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_AHAD INNER JOIN tbl_Ex_p ON tbl_AHAD.ID = tbl_Ex_p.ID " & _
    "SET tbl_AHAD.Last_Insp_Date = Date() "
End Function
```

This is the sub that runs along with it's function after the DoCmd.OpenForm "SelectPrinter", , , , , acDialog

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
cboDestination = ""
m_GetPrinters cboDestination
cboDestination.SetFocus
cboDestination.ListIndex = 0

End Sub

Public Sub m_GetPrinters(ByRef objListOrCombo As Object)
Dim objPrinter          As Printer
Dim intNbOfPrinters     As Integer

intNbOfPrinters = Printers.Count - 1
For Each objPrinter In Printers
    objListOrCombo.AddItem objPrinter.DeviceName
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specifically open the form in dialogue mode:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "SelectPrinter", , , , , acDialog
```

Thus, your code will not stop, but it turns to the form opened and silently waits until that form is closed - then the code will proceed.

If you wish to open the form and have the function `PrintReports()` to continue without taking notice of the form, then don't use the `acDialog` setting.